# Como posso passar a resposa desta função para um arquivo php chamado geolocation via ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: Estou correto em supor que por "esta função", você está se referindo ao conteúdo do elemento `x`? Isto é, a _string_ "Latitude: XXX<br>Longitude: OOO"?

Comment: Sim senhor, só quero retornar a latitude e longitude.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o seguinte script para pegar a geolocalização a cada 20 segundos e enviar a uma página PHP para gravar no banco de dados.
Pode não ser exatamente o que você quer, mas é um ponto de partida.
Crie o arquivo `geolocation.php` para tratar seus dados.

```
       var options = {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          timeout: 5000,
          maximumAge: 0
        };

        function success(pos) {

          var crd = pos.coords;

          console.log('Sua posição atual é:');
          console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
          console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
          console.log('Mais ou menos ' + crd.accuracy + ' metros.');
          console.log('Velocidade ' + crd.speed);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "geolocation.php",
            data: {latitude : crd.latitude, longitude : crd.longitude, precisao : crd.accuracy}
        });

          navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);

        };

        function error(err) {
          console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
        };

        var watchId;        
        watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
        setInterval(function(){ watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options); },20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do Pedro Augusto, mas utilizando o trecho de código que você postou, o mais fácil seria fazer o *post* na função `showPosition()`, embora neste caso talvez ela devesse mudar de nome para `treatPosition()` ou algo do gênero:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (! navigator.geolocation) {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                          "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
            $.ajax({
                url: "path/to/service.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    long: position.coords.longitude,
                    text: x.innerHTML
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

É claro, o código de verdade depende das características do serviço: o que ele espera com relação a método, nomes de parâmetros, qual a URL, qual o tipo MIME do pedido, etc.